# How do I replace build values in a java program during a maven build

Tags: java, maven, properties, ibm-midrange

I am writing plugins for IBM Application Runtime Expert for i.  In the process of building the template, the iSeries packaging program replaces the manifest and removes the resources directory.  I do not want to upload the properties via the other files part of ARE.

Is there a way to get maven to replace values in a .java program?  I am not using Spring.

ex:

```
public class foo {
  int version = ${application.version};
}
```

Comment: You generally don't want to do that, but resource filtering lets you do this in a `.properties` file, which is then pretty easy to read from your code.

Comment: True.  I tried using a properties file, but the packaging code on the iSeries is removing the entire resources directory.  My MANIFEST.MF is completely replaced during the packaging as well. The only way I can think to keep it away from the packager is to put it in a class.

Comment: I would suggest if you really have such issues you should take a look at https://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/ ...

Comment: That looks like it may be perfect.  Thank-you.